# Cannot get Hyper-V to work on Windows 10: The hypervisor is not running

Tags: hyper-v

Hyper-V installs without apparent problem, but then any attempt at launching a virtual machine throws this error :

```
'<virtual machine name>' failed to start.

Virtual machine '<virtual machine name>' could not be started because the hypervisor is not running.
```

System info:

- Windows 10 Enterprise 1803 17134.523
- ASUS PRIME B350-PLUS
- AMD Ryzen 5 1600X

Here is the output of the various software I've checked :

- ASUS UEFI BIOS Utility > Advanced Mode > Advanced > CPU Configuration

  ```
  NX Mode                     Enabled
  SVM Mode                    Enabled
  SMT Mode                    Auto
  Core Leveling Mode          Automatic mode
  ```
- Task Manager > Performance

  ```
  Virtualization: Enabled
  ```
- msinfo32.exe > System Summary

  ```
  Hyper-V - VM Monitor Mode Extensions                   Yes
  Hyper-V - Second Level Address Translation Extensions  Yes
  Hyper-V - Virtualization Enabled in Firmware           Yes
  Hyper-V - Data Execution Protection                    Yes
  ```
- coreinfo.exe -v

  ```
  AMD Ryzen 5 1600X Six-Core Processor
  AMD64 Family 23 Model 1 Stepping 1, AuthenticAMD
  Microcode signature: 00000000
  HYPERVISOR      -       Hypervisor is present
  SVM             *       Supports AMD hardware-assisted virtualization
  NP              *       Supports AMD nested page tables (SLAT)
  ```
- bcdedit.exe > Windows Boot Loader

  ```
  nx                      OptIn
  hypervisorlaunchtype    Auto
  ```
- PowerShell > Get-Service -DisplayName Hyper-V*

  ```
  Status   Name               DisplayName
  ------   ----               -----------
  Running  vmcompute          Hyper-V Host Compute Service
  Stopped  vmicguestinterface Hyper-V Guest Service Interface
  Stopped  vmicheartbeat      Hyper-V Heartbeat Service
  Stopped  vmickvpexchange    Hyper-V Data Exchange Service
  Stopped  vmicrdv            Hyper-V Remote Desktop Virtualizati...
  Stopped  vmicshutdown       Hyper-V Guest Shutdown Service
  Stopped  vmictimesync       Hyper-V Time Synchronization Service
  Stopped  vmicvmsession      Hyper-V PowerShell Direct Service
  Stopped  vmicvss            Hyper-V Volume Shadow Copy Requestor
  Running  vmms               Hyper-V Virtual Machine Management
  ```

I have found multiple similar threads on this website and others, and have already tried (all of them to no avail) :

- Uninstalling and reinstalling Hyper-V (multiple times)
- Rebooting the machine (cold boot, multiple times)
- Upgrading my BIOS
- Upgrading the motherboard chipset driver

Any idea about the next course of action?

Comment: What security software do you have installed.  Be sure you disable any feature that might be using hardware virtualization.  You should also verify Core Isolation is disabled.

Comment: There is no security software, except for Windows Defender. Core isolation > Memory integrity is disabled.

Comment: What is your CPU?

Comment: As mentioned in the post, it is an AMD Ryzen 5 1600X.

Comment: @MathieuRenda - Possible duplicate: https://superuser.com/questions/1444769/hyper-v-virtual-machine-could-not-be-started-because-the-hypervisor-is-not-run

Comment: @Ramhound Very interesting. I tried updating to 1903, but the update keeps failing. We might be onto something here.

Comment: @MathieuRenda - There was another Ryzen hardware virtualization question but the user was trying to run Android Studio, apparently there might be a conflict with 1803 and 1809 and Ryzen when you use the Hypervisor Platform.  Doesn’t explain your error but somebody else had your same error and it was fixed by upgrading to 1903.

Comment: [Sorry...The user actually upgraded to 20H1 Insider Preview in their case.](https://superuser.com/questions/1442275/amd-processor-what-am-i-doing-wrong-that-im-not-being-able-to-use-any-emulato)

Comment: 1803 is known to have issues with Hyper-V. Upgrading to 1903 seems to fix the problem for most, but as you stated, you're also having problems with that.

Answer (score 0):

Your hardware can run Hyper-V according to the specs, so the problem is probably
with some settings.

Check in the BIOS under
*Advanced Frequency Settings > Advanced CPU Core Settings*, if the option
named "SVM mode" is set to Enabled. If it is not, enable it, save the BIOS,
turn-off the computer and do a cold boot.

If this does not help, open an elevated Command Prompt and run this command:

```
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto
```

then reboot the computer, again with a cold boot.

If this does not work either, check if your setup is really capable of running
Hyper-V with the
[AMD-V with RVI Hyper V Compatibility Utility](http://download.amd.com/techdownloads/AMD-VwithRVI_Hyper-V_CompatibilityUtility.zip),
running it in elevated mode.

Comment: These two options are already activated, and I've performed multiple cold boots since. The tool says "This system is compatible with Hyper-V". Despite all this, no VM is starting.

Comment: Is this the same for both 32-bit and 64-bit VMs?

Comment: I don't think you can create a 32-bit VM _per se_ in Hyper-V. You can install a 32-bit _operating system_ on a VM. Here, I cannot do that because the VM doesn't even start.

Comment: Try this: Run `gpedit.msc` and go to *Local Computer Policy > Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Device Guard > Turn on Virtualization Based Security*, and set to *Disabled*. Reboot.

Comment: You can't even add Hyper-V feature without enabling SVM mode first, so this is irrelevant.

Comment: @AlexG: I don't understand your remark and downvote.

Answer (score -1):

OSes can only run one hyper-Visor at one time. Is it possible you have another one running such as VMware, virtual box. Or maybe a program that utilizes that such as NOX?
Since you mention your on enterprise is there any GPOs blocking use of Hyper-V.

To test I would install a Spare SSD and install windows 10 Pro and see if the issue persists.

Comment: There is no other hypervisor AFAIK. I'm going to follow your suggestion and reinstall the OS.

Comment: let me know if that works and throw an up vote for the input :)