# Whenever I'm trying to open up an Android Emulator on either VS Code or Android Studio, I get "Windows Hypervisor Platform accelerator is operational"

Tags: virtualization, visual-studio-code, android-studio, hypervisor, hardware-virtualization

I'm trying to develop an app using [Flutter](https://flutter.dev) but whenever I try and open up an Android Emulator I always get "Windows Hypervisor Platform accelerator is operational:

> Windows Hypervisor Platform accelerator is operational
>   C:\Users\thesl\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-i386.exe:
>   WHPX: Failed to emulate MMIO access with EmulatorReturnStatus: 2
>   (InternalEmulationFailure )
>   C:\Users\thesl\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-i386.exe:
>   whpx_vcpu { emulator=00000000315c4dd0, window_registered=false,
>   interruptable=true, tpr=0, apic_base=fee00900,
>   interruption_pending=false }
>   C:\Users\thesl\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-i386.exe:
>   WHV_MEMORY_ACCESS_CONTEXT { Instruction={ size=16, bytes='A1 F0 00 E0
>   FE 80 CC 01 A3 F0 00 E0 FE C7 05 50 ' }, AccessInfo={ AccessType=0,
>   GpaUnmapped=1, GvaValid=0, AsUINT32=4 }, Gpa=fee000f0, Gva=0 }
>   C:\Users\thesl\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-i386.exe:
>   WHPX: Failed to exec a virtual processor emulator: INFO:
>   QtLogger.cpp:66: Warning: QObject::~QObject: Timers cannot be stopped
>   from another thread ((null):0, (null))

I obviously have Windows Hypervisor Platform installed and the SDK Manager is up-to-date so I want to know what's going on and how I can solve this annoying issue. Both VS Code and Android Studio are up-to-date aswell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have to upgrade to the Windows Insider fast ring. What build number are you on?

https://superuser.com/a/1443837

Comment: Thank you, I have already done that! It works fine now but it would be nice for Windows to fix it.