# Hyper-v - Virtual Machine could not be started because the hypervisor is not running ... But it is

Tags: windows-10, hyper-v, docker-for-windows

I've seen various threads on this subject but none of them solve the issue I have. I want to be able to run Docker for Windows on this machine but even though it installs i get a problem at start up. The problem appears to be nothing to do with Docker, as no VM will start.

[image: Error from Hyper-v management console]

For reference, I did successfully run Hyper-v when I first got the machine (late 18) and ran Docker for Windows OK.  But I had to go back to VirtualBox for a while and now that I can go back to hyper-v I find I get the problem.

Machine is a Lenovo Thinkpad P51 with 32GB memory, running Windows 10

bcdedit reports:

```
hypervisorlaunchtype    Auto
```

systeminfo reports:

```
Hyper-V Requirements:      VM Monitor Mode Extensions: Yes
                           Virtualization Enabled In Firmware: Yes
                           Second Level Address Translation: Yes
                           Data Execution Prevention Available: Yes
```

The services - I think this is correct:
[image: The services - I think this is correct]

The Windows features show as installed:
[image: The windows features show as installed]

Where am I going wrong ? Any other logs/messages that i can look at ?

FWIW - I can disable Hyper-V and run VirtualBox without any issues....

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/questions/1441858/cannot-get-hyper-v-to-work-on-windows-10-the-hypervisor-is-not-running

Comment: What version of Windows 10 are you running.  There have been numerous Docker questions linked to this same issue recently.

Comment: Running Win 10 Pro - 1803

Comment: I'll upgrade to 1903 .... need to find an IT guy as it looks like the windows update upgrade is disabled by corporate policy.

Answer (score 1):

As per the suggestion from @Ramhound i checked the Windows version and as it was old 1803 I did the upgrade to the new 1903 (May19) build.

This has fixed the VM startup problem and i'm now working again.

The fix may be that the update fixed a configuration problem during the update or it may have fixed a bug. Either way i'm working again.